# SwiftyJSON and adding to existing [String: AnyObject] dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

This is the `JSON` I am looking to parse with the `SwiftyJSON` library:

```
{
    array: [
        { a: "something", b: "something" },
        { a: "something", b: "something" },
        { a: "something", b: "something" }
    ]
}
```

The catch is that the array count will have variable amount of objects. Normally I would just create a `Dictionary` with `[String: AnyObject]`, but can't do a `for` loop inside it.

```
var parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "array": [
        ]
    ]
```

Is there any way I can append/add [String: AnyObject] elements to an existing `Dictionary` ("array" dictionary)?

I would then convert it to a `JSON` with the `SwiftyJSON` lib.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest constructing the inner array first. It is possible to reach into your nested data structure and modify things, but tricky because you have to be very careful about types.

```
var innerArray: [AnyObject] = []
for i in 0...2 {
    innerArray.append(["a":"something","b":"something"])
}
var parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["array": innerArray]
```